# Why is PROC MEANS so memory intensive?

Tags: sas

I was summarizing a dataset with approximately 1 million rows by 5 category variables.  I initially tried this with PROC MEANS but kept getting memory warnings and the process took forever.  I ended up just using PROC SQL with a GROUP BY statement and the whole process only took around ~ 10 seconds.  Why is their such a performance difference?  My understanding was that PROC MEANS just creates an SQL statement in the background so I would assume the two methods would be very similar.

Comment: You will need to show the actual code you used to get any explanation. If a simple GROUP BY got you the results you wanted then perhaps you forgot to include the NWAY option in your PROC MEANS code.  Or you forgot to add the NOPRINT option to prevent it from generating large output you didn't want.

Comment: SAS didn't support SQL until one of the 6.x releases.  I'm pretty sure `proc means` predates this and uses it's own code base.

Comment: Did your PROC MEANS step have a BY statement or a CLASS statement?  CLASS statement requires much more memory, because the running totals are held in memory for every level of the CLASS variable as it processes the entire dataset.  BY statement relies on sort order.  PROC MEANS is not just creating SQL in the background, except I suppose in the case where you have implicit pass-through to a relational database. Even so, 1 million records is small to be hitting problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the `proc` notation, you can also use `proc summary` instead of `proc means` or `proc sql` as it's almost identical to `proc means` but for some reason it uses less memory.

Not sure why this is the case but I know in the past I have avoided memory issues by switching code from `proc means` to `proc summary`.